# Does the AnyVal with AnyRef as a parameter make sense in Scala?

Tags: scala, anyref

Does below construct makes any sense? Are any benefits of using it?

```
final case class Id(uuid: UUID) extends AnyVal
```

As I understand above construct, Id doesn't have to be instantiated in some scenarios described [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). But I have some doubts because I didn't find any example with AnyRef as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, it should work with `AnyRefs`, keep in mind that on some occasions it does not work and the compiler ends up instantiating a class. However, I had never seen it used together with a **case class**, as it is usually used together with an **implicit class** to provide zero-cost extension methods.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `extends AnyVal` is used with case classes as well.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Oh, cool. Do you know if that still ensures there is no instantiation? I assume what it does is provide all methods that a **case class** provides _(like `copy`)_ with zero cost? Or what is the intention?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess `def`s are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this example makes sense. Extending `AnyVal` is useful when you want specific semantics for a type, but don't want to pay the additional allocation cost that come along with it. For example, say you have a typeclass instance for outputting string representation of values, like `Show[A]`, and you want to give specific semantics to `UUID`, but there already exists an instance of `Show[UUID]` in scope which you can't control, this is when wrapping a type and introducing an implicit typeclass for it can be useful.

Do note that `AnyVal`  may end up allocating instances of the wrapper class in specific cases as mentioned in [this documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> - a value class is treated as another type.
> - a value class is assigned to an array.
> - doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks! So as I understand it makes sense to use it for type safety of UUID or String identifiers and use as data not as in ad hoc polimorfism, am I right?